# Python Refactoring Tools For Renaming/Moving

Tags: python, refactoring

I am looking for a python tool that will allow me to specifically rename and move modules.

When I program, I do a LOT of reorganizing things, moving items from package to package, adding new packages, and renaming files. I come from Java, where this is unreasonably easy to do in an IDE.

Right now I'm using aptana, and its refactoring support is decent for renaming a class method or variable, but when it comes to moving a module from one package to another, I see no way around trying a find/replace on your own.

Does anybody know of a reasonable tool to move/rename modules. I've heard of rope, but have not fully investigated yet.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [rope](https://github.com/python-rope/rope) is the library you're looking for:

> **Features**
>
> ...
>
> - Rename everything!
>
> ...
>
> - Move class/function/module/package/method